# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ajax' of undefined in GeoJson Leaflet

Tags: jquery, django, ajax, leaflet, geojson

I am using ajax query for geoJson data. However, I am not able to load the data into the leaflet maps. Using a sample ajax query such as this, when I look in the console I am able to find the data. Not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help will be greatly appreciated :) Thanks.

[

```js
    $.ajax({ 
        type: 'GET', 
        url: 'location', 
        //data: { get_param: 'value' }, 
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data, status) { 
            console.log(data);
            geojson = data
        }
    });

    function our_layers(map,options){
        var Location = L.geojson.ajax("{% url 'location' %}",{

        });

    };
```

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmY1Q.png)

Comment: What is you problem? To use `L.geoJson.ajax` you have to add a library to your code, also you have to write the "J" uppercase. To add the data to the map you have to add the result to the map. `L.geoJSON(geojson).addTo(map);`

Comment: Hi, thank you so much. I followed your code of capitalizing the J and it works. Appreciate your help :)